# $ dP/dt=kP^2 , P(0)=2, dP/dt = 1$ for $P(t)= 10,$ what is P?

Tags: calculus

Full Question:
Suppose a population P of rodents satisfies the differential equation $dP/dt= kP^2 $. Initially there are P(0)= 2 rodents, and their number is increasing at the rate dP/dt= 1 rodent per month when there are P = 10 rodents. How long will will it take this population to grow to a a hundred rodents.

i found that k should be 1/100 because $P'=kp^2$, and  P'(0)=4/100, what should i next for finding P?

P.S: The result must be P(t)=100/(50-t)

Comment: It's a separable equation and can be rewritten:
$$
dt = {dP \over k \, P^2}.
$$
Now integrate on each site with respect to the appropriate variable:
$$
\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} dt = \int_{P(t_{1})}^{P(t_{2})} {dP \over k \, P^2}.
$$

Comment: @user8960 but the result must have to be p(t)=100/(50-t)

Comment: You should get your title correct. what is small $p$? You are looking for P and you say $P(t)=10$. That is confusing. Do you mean $\dfrac{dP}{dt}\left|_{t_0}=1$ for $P(t_0)=10$?

Comment: @MrYouMath I have just wrote full question to end all confusing, hopefully.

Comment: @codemonkey, I am not contradicting the result you expect.  I am just telling you how to solve the differential equation.

Comment: @user8960 oh my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate variables and then integrate as mentioned in the comments.

\begin{align*}
  dP &= kP^2 \, dt \\[0.3cm]
  \frac{dP}{P^2} &= k \, dt\\[0.3cm]
  \int \frac{dP}{P^2} &= \int k \, dt\\[0.3cm]
  -\frac1P &= kt + C\\[0.3cm]
  P &= -\frac1{kt + C}
\end{align*}

$P'(0) = 4/100$, $P(0) = 2$, and $P'(t) = kP(t)^2$ tell us $4/100 = 4k$, and so $k = 1/100$ as you've found.  Finding $C$ is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is the solution $P=0, \forall t$.

Looking for a non trivial solution, separating the variables you get:
$$\frac{\mathrm dP}{P^2} = k\mathrm dt$$
so 
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dP}{P^2}=\int k\mathrm dt \; \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{P}=kt +C$$
where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant to be determined. Making the equation explicit with respect to  $P$:
$$P = -\frac{1}{kt+C}$$
Now you have to find the value of $C$ such that the function $P$ satisfies the initial condition (of the Cauchy problem), but first you need to find the value of $k$ which is $\tfrac{1}{100}$.
$$P(t) = \frac{-100}{t+100C}$$
$$P(0) = \frac{-100}{100C} = \frac{-1}{C} = 2 \Rightarrow C=-\frac{1}{2}$$
So, in the end:
$$P(t) = \frac{-100}{t-50} = \frac{100}{50-t}$$